# ACRA Sends empty report all the time to my backend server

Tags: android, acra

The following ACRA configuration sends empty report to my backend server:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    formUri = "http://myserver/SubmitCrash.aspx",
    httpMethod=org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.POST,
    customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

But if I reconfigure ACRA to send the report to email it sends it without any issue, do someone know why could ACRA send empty report to my backend server?

Here is my logcat:

```
04-09 20:57:51.066: E/Trace(661): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-10 09:39:49.249: E/Trace(641): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-10 09:39:50.270: D/ACRA(641): ACRA is enabled for com.MyApp, intializing...
04-10 09:39:50.352: D/ACRA(641): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.MyApp/files
04-10 09:39:50.660: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 10% free 7423K/8199K, paused 28ms+22ms, total 125ms
04-10 09:39:50.680: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
04-10 09:39:50.680: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-10 09:39:50.680: E/ACRA(641): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.MyApp. Building report.
04-10 09:39:50.700: D/ACRA(641): Using default Report Fields
04-10 09:39:51.510: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_CONCURRENT freed 354K, 11% free 7541K/8391K, paused 32ms+26ms, total 143ms
04-10 09:39:52.159: I/ACRA(641): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
04-10 09:39:52.199: D/ACRA(641): Retrieving logcat output...
04-10 09:39:52.419: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_CONCURRENT freed 540K, 12% free 7563K/8583K, paused 31ms+9ms, total 98ms
04-10 09:39:52.419: D/dalvikvm(641): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
04-10 09:39:52.489: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 12% free 7561K/8583K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
04-10 09:39:52.489: I/dalvikvm-heap(641): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.869MB for 19690-byte allocation
04-10 09:39:52.559: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 13% free 7567K/8647K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
04-10 09:39:52.569: D/ACRA(641): Writing crash report file 1428658792000.stacktrace.
04-10 09:39:52.709: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 153K, 13% free 7545K/8647K, paused 41ms, total 43ms
04-10 09:39:52.759: D/ACRA(641): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
04-10 09:39:52.759: D/ACRA(641): Mark all pending reports as approved.
04-10 09:39:52.759: D/ACRA(641): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.MyApp/files
04-10 09:39:52.781: D/ACRA(641): #checkAndSendReports - start
04-10 09:39:52.781: D/ACRA(641): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.MyApp/files
04-10 09:39:52.789: I/ACRA(641): Sending file 1428658792000-approved.stacktrace
04-10 09:39:52.789: D/ACRA(641): Waiting for Toast + worker...
04-10 09:39:53.029: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 197K, 13% free 7574K/8647K, paused 42ms, total 43ms
04-10 09:39:53.110: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 12% free 7641K/8647K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
04-10 09:39:53.110: I/dalvikvm-heap(641): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.992MB for 65552-byte allocation
04-10 09:39:53.169: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 14% free 7609K/8775K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
04-10 09:39:53.189: D/ACRA(641): Connect to http://myserver/SubmitCrash.aspx
04-10 09:39:53.519: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_CONCURRENT freed 411K, 14% free 7630K/8775K, paused 21ms+5ms, total 63ms
04-10 09:39:53.519: D/dalvikvm(641): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 43ms
04-10 09:39:53.599: D/ACRA(641): Sending request to http://myserver/SubmitCrash.aspx
04-10 09:39:54.969: D/ACRA(641): #checkAndSendReports - finish
04-10 09:39:55.039: D/ACRA(641): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MyApp/com.MyApp.MainActivity}:  java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a crash
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a crash
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.MyApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:218)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-10 09:39:55.059: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
04-10 09:39:59.819: I/Process(641): Sending signal. PID: 641 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Http PUT Method as below:

`httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT;`

Answer (score 0):

As logcat says, you haven't fully configured ACRA.
ACRA is complaining that you haven't provided `resDialogText`, which also suggests that the rest of your ACRA config is not as listed in your question.

```
04-09 20:57:51.066: E/Trace(661): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-09 20:57:51.826: W/ACRA(661): Error : 
04-09 20:57:51.826: W/ACRA(661): org.acra.ACRAConfigurationException: DIALOG     mode: you have to define at least the resDialogText parameters in your     application @ReportsCrashes() annotation.
```

Comment: ACRA can reach my server because my server add empty report in the database each time a crash happens.

Comment: But is your server sending a response back to the ACRA client? If it's not then the client will believe the report has never been sent and will keep trying to resend it.

Comment: How to send back the response to the client?

Comment: Acra do HTTP Post request...as far I know with http post the sender should not wait response back!

Comment: Depends entirely upon the signature and semantic of the call.  ACRA needs to be confident that the server has received the error. So if it doesn't get a HTTP 200 in response then it will resend. This is pretty common behaviour with web requests.

Comment: I send http status code 200 but still getting empty report.

Comment: So what does your logcat say when the report is sent? Post it

Comment: Very sorry I sent the wrong logcat it's for dialog mode, please check the updated logcat which is for silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to config these parameters in `@ReportsCrashes`

```
    resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
    resDialogIcon = R.drawable.dialog_logo,
    resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title,
    resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt,
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast,
    reportType = Type.JSON
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very sorry I sent the wrong logcat it's for dialog mode, please check the updated logcat which is for silent mode.